# Positive lookback

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to come up with a small program to scan a code-base for a few patterns, we are mostly interested in the two below

```
Function("Hello World")
Function("Hello World", "Max 10 Chars")
```

I`ve tried to use Positive lookback, but not able to figure out where I'm going wrong,
The link below works without lookback

https://regexr.com/4v7so

When changing the pattern to
`Function\("([\w\s\d]+)"(?<=[\,\s"]+)([\w\s\d]+")\)`
it stops working,

I`m pretty new to this side of regEx, any leads will be helpful

Comment: What output do you expect? Note `(?<=[\,\s"]+)` does not consume chars, so `Function\("([\w\s\d]+)"(?<=[\,\s"]+)([\w\s\d]+")\)` can only [match strings like `Function("Function"End")`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Function%5c%28%22%28%5b%5cw%5cs%5cd%5d%2b%29%22%28%3f%3c%3d%5b%5c%2c%5cs%22%5d%2b%29%28%5b%5cw%5cs%5cd%5d%2b%22%29%5c%29&i=Function%28%22Function%22End%22%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Function\("([\w\s\d]+)"(?:\s*,\s*"([\w\s\d]+)")*\)
```

As any additional argument to the function has a `,` char as a seperator you can use the non-capture group `(?:  )*` regex to capture 0-n occurrences of such a pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to get the job done using your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

This RegEx matches any function with name 'Function' and any amount of string literal parameters:

```
Function\("([\w\s\d]+)"(\s*\,\s*"[\w\s\d]+")*\)
```

This one will only match functions with name 'Function' and one or two string literal parameters:

```
Function\("([\w\s\d]+)"(\s*\,\s*"[\w\s\d]+")?\)
```